# strtotime () not converting to timestamp

Tags: php, mysql, date, unix-timestamp

I have a loop and in it the date is coming in different formats like for some values it will be like `'10-13-2013 04:31'` and for some it is like `'2013-10-14T22:14:40-0700'`. I tried to store this in DB as the value of a datetime/timestamp column but it is failing for the first format that is `10-13-2013 04:31`. So I tried to convert it into UNIX timestamp using `strtotime()`. It is working for some values and is storing zero for values like `'10-13-2013 04:31'`. I think this is because it is considering the second value as month and so failing. My code is as follows :

```
foreach($reports as $report){
    echo strtotime($report->transactionDate);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`strtotime()` is unable to parse `mm-dd-yyyy` format. Instead you should use [DateTime::createFromFormat()](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php), like this:

```
$date = '10-13-2013 04:31';
$obj  = DateTime::createFromFormat('m-d-Y H:i', $date);
$date = $obj->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```